# GPU access via QGIS python plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, osgeo4w

My Setup

1. Windows 10 (with latest updates)
2. QGIS 3.0.0-Girona (QGIS code revision 001c80b0c3)
3. QGIS Python plugin: sys.version gives '3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
4. Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12).  Taken from OSGeo4W python prompt.

This is the code in question:

```
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM']=r'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\nvvm\bin\nvvm64_32_0.dll'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE']=r'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\nvvm\libdevice'

from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def pow(a, b):
    return a ** b

vec_size = 100000000

a = b = np.array(np.random.sample(vec_size), dtype=np.float32)
c = np.zeros(vec_size, dtype=np.float32)

start = timer()
c = pow(a, b)
duration = timer() - start

print(duration)
```

When this code is run in OSGeo4W shell using the following command "python3 Cuda_yes.py" I get the following (which is working)...
[image]

When this code is run in QGIS python plug-in, using the following command

```
exec(open('C:/Users/User/Documents/Cuda_yes.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\npyufunc\decorators.py", line 120, in wrap
    vec.add(sig)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\npyufunc\deviceufunc.py", line 384, in add
    corefn, return_type = self._compile_core(devfnsig)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\vectorizers.py", line 17, in _compile_core
    cudevfn = cuda.jit(sig, device=True, inline=True)(self.pyfunc)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\decorators.py", line 102, in device_jit
    debug=debug)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 160, in compile_device
    return DeviceFunction(pyfunc, return_type, args, inline=True, debug=False)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 191, in __init__
    debug=self.debug, inline=self.inline)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 36, in core
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 64, in compile_cuda
    locals={})
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 779, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 362, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 738, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 725, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 248, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 658, in stage_nopython_backend
    self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=False)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 613, in _backend
    lowered = lowerfn()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 600, in backend_nopython_mode
    self.flags)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 897, in native_lowering_stage
    lower = lowering.Lower(targetctx, library, fndesc, interp)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.env = Environment.from_fndesc(self.fndesc)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 21, in from_fndesc
    mod = fndesc.lookup_module()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\funcdesc.py", line 77, in lookup_module
    return sys.modules[self.modname]
KeyError: "Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)\n'__console__'"
```

I have a feeling the error is in the call [*exec()*], but I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: If you write a short .py file that uses `exec` to run the same file, does that work from the OSGeo4W python shell? In other words, is it QGIS, or is it `exec`?

Comment: Further investigation is showing that it is the following causing issues, in QGIS only!... @vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def pow(a, b):
    return a ** b

Comment: Yes, the exec works because I have a 'non-gpu' version that works in QGIS... exec(open('C:/Users/User/Documents/Cuda_no.py'.encode('utf-8')).read()).  Also, if I run exec(open('C:/Users/User/Documents/Cuda_yes.py'.encode('utf-8')).read()) in the ODGeo4W shell, all is good!

Comment: Removing the @ disables the numba decorator  compilation so your function will be running in python only.

Comment: Hi Luke, you are correct.  I ran a few tests and monitored my GPU/CPU when the '@' is in place or not.  When the @ is there, GPU cycles are active and when '@' is not there, CPU cycles are more active with no GPU cycles.  The vectorize does, however improve the performance when running the calculations.  I'll delete my comment above stating the problem was identified (it was a false positive).
In short, I still cannot run @vectorized in QGIS python plugin.

Comment: Perhaps don't use `exec`. Re-write your script as a module, move all the code below the `pow` function into a `main` function, import your module and run `cuda_yes.main()` directly.